# Reference request on how to get a linear optimisation problem from absolute value objective function

Tags: optimization, reference-request, linear-programming

Consider the following optimisation problem
$$
\min_{\theta\in \mathbb{R}^K} \sum_{l=1}^L |r_l-c'\theta|\\
\text{s.t. } R\theta\leq q
$$
where :

- $r\equiv (r_1,...,r_L)$ is an $L\times 1$ vector of known real numbers
- $c$ is a $K\times 1$ vector of known real numbers
- $R$ is an $M\times K$ matrix of known real numbers
- $q$ is an $M\times 1$ vector of known real numbers

An exercise I'm trying to solve maintains that this problem can be rewritten as the following linear programming:
$$
\min_{\theta\in \mathbb{R}^K, y^+\in \mathbb{R}^L, y^-\in \mathbb{R}^L,} \sum_{l=1}^L (y^+_{l}+y^-_{l})\\
\text{s.t. } R\theta\leq q\\
r_l-c'\theta=y^+_{l}-y^-_{l} \text{ }\forall l=1,...,L\\
y^+_l\geq 0, y^-_l\geq 0 \text{ }\forall l=1,...,L\\
$$
Is it true and could you give a reference for such a result?

Comment: An explanation: $y^+ \ge 0$ captures the positive part of $r - c \theta$ and $y^- \ge 0$ its negative part. So we have $r - c \theta = y^+ - y^-$ and $|r - c \theta| = y^+ + y^-$.

Comment: If you do not have the copy of the book by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis, you can just look up this one exercise from their book: https://math.solverer.com/library/dimitris_bertsimas/introduction_to_linear_optimization/exercise_1-5?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard reference for linear optimization is *Introduction to linear optimization* by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis. This reformulation is described in Section 1, page 18 (3rd edition), in a subsection named 'Problems involving absolute values'.